# TypeError: Object #<ServerResponse> has no method 'redirect'

Tags: node.js, node.js-connect

I have a below code where I'm trying to redirect the URL. Initially the user will hit `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`, which has to be redirected to different URL.

```
 var connect = require('connect'),
     app = connect();
        .use(connectRoute(function (router) {
            router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
                var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
                if (ip == "127.0.0.1")
                res.redirect("some other url");
                
            })
        }))
    
    
    app.listen(5000);
```

I'm getting the error `TypeError: Object #<ServerResponse> has no method 'redirect'`. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. Any help on this will be really helpful.

Answer (score 6):

You're trying to use a method that isn't defined in Node's [ServerResponse](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse). The `res.redirect` method is defined by [the Express framework](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.redirect) ([see relevant source](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/3.4.4/lib/response.js#L685)).

If you want to use the helper methods defined by express, create an express server and don't use the raw connect library.